# testing input type color with protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I have an input that uses the OS's color picker. Is there any way to test that the color picker comes up?

```
<input id="accent-color" type="color" ng-model="color">
```

I suspect I know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you cannot manipulate the color picker as a real user would do.

You can, though, set it's value via `executeScript()`:

```
var elm = element(by.id("accent-color"));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1]);", elm, "#fe2235");
```

The color value would be set, but do not expect the picker color that you see on the page to be changed with the new color value.

Comment: I figured the answer would ultimately be a no. Thats ok, im using [spectrum js](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) in place of the OS color picker. we were just trying to be lazy.

Answer (score 0):

In protractor, you can select any attribute of css with `[]`'s:

```
 element(by.css('[type="color"]'))
```

This is effectively testing for a color picker, since a `type="color"`, is exactly that, but it's not really testing if it's come up.

There is a way to then cycle through the options that have popped up and select one, I appreciate this is a little vague but this video contains your answer:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHyp7vk7DeE&index=6&list=PL_noPv5wmuO-mnEq8Sf0h43QRk-Gk2Cvb